# How do I serialize and then parse such JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

I have javascript code and objects in it, I need to collect those objects and serialize them into array. I use such function:

```
function getData () {
    var objects = [];
    for (var i in this) {
        if (this[i] instanceof Object)
            if (this[i].isShow())
                objects.push(JSON.stringify(this[i]));
    }
    JSInterface.setLocationsData(locations);
}
```

Then I need to parse this in Java. I get following:

```
{"title":"sample1", value:1}, {"title":"sample2", value:2}
```

How do I parse it? It's not an JSONArray, so I added:

```
JSInterface.setLocationsData("["+locations+"]");
```

Any better solution?

Comment: That isn't valid JSON. Aside from that, you'd use a JSON parser in Java of which there are many. A simple google search of "Java JSON" will point you in the right direction.

Comment: I use org.json. The question was how to make JSON valid.

Comment: Then I would suggest re-writing your question noting that the problem is that you don't know how to produce valid JSON and dropping anything having to do with Java from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the stringify on the last line:

```
function getData () {
    var objects = [];
    for (var i in this) {
        if (this[i] instanceof Object)
            if (this[i].isShow())
                objects.push(this[i]);
    }
    JSInterface.setLocationsData(JSON.stringify(objects));
}
```